# Insert array of tags on blog post creation in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a relatively simple Blog Post object named `Blog` where each newly created (or updated) post has a few tags (in the shape of a json array) assigned to it which needs to be looped through and inserted into a `blog_link_tags` join table so each blog post can have multiple tags assigned to it.

At the moment my code looks like this, however this seems wrong.

```
public function insertAction(Request $request)
{

    $blogPost
        ->setTitle( $request->request->get('post_title', '') )
        ->setBody( $request->request->get('post_body', '') );

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($blogPost);

    $tags = new BlogLinkTag();
    $tags->setBlogId( */get blog post id* );
    $tags->setTagId(1);

    $em->persist($tags);
    $em->flush();


}
```

Is there a better way to perform this? For example, something like this makes much more sense:

```
$blogPost
    ->setTitle( $request->request->get('post_title', '') )
    ->setBody( $request->request->get('post_body', '') )
    ->setTags( json_decode($request->request->get('post_tags')) );
```

Comment: it looks like you want a `one_to_many` relation, take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) on how to do that in Doctrin2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [many-to-many relationship](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional).
You do need an extra table to link a `BlogPost` to a `Tag`, but you don't need a `BlogLinkTag` entity, the ORM will take care of this.

What you should do, is to have a `$tags` property in your `BlogPost`:

```php
class BlogPost
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $body;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag") @JoinTable(
     *  name="blog_link_tags",
     *  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="blogPostId", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tagId", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $tags;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addTag(Tag $tag) {
        $this->tags->add($tag);
    }

    public function removeTag(Tag $tag) {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
    }
}
```

When you persist `BlogPost`, its tags will be saved together, without any explicit action from you.

The only issue as compared to what you wanted to achieve in your question, is that you need to instantiate every `Tag` to add/remove it to the `BlogPost`. You will be working with objects, not ids!